# Finding variables dynamically

Tags: javascript, variables

I have 3 defined variables.

```
var age = 25;
var name = 'vincent';
var work = 'painter';
```

below function required to assign corresponding values to the variables.

```
function assign(_data){
    //_data contains "age_25" and it might be "Name_Raja" 
    //this can be any one of the three variables.
}
```

How to identify the corresponding variable from the data?

Comment: is _data a list? why not a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function assign(_data){
    window[_data.split("_")[0]] = _data.split("_")[1];
}
```

This assigns the value of the corresponding key.

Answer (score 2):

Use `indexOf` of to identify what data contains

```
var name = '',
    age = 0,
    work = '';

function assign(_data) {
    _data = _data.toLowerCase();
    if (_data.indexOf('name_')) {
        name = _data.split('_')[1];
    } 
    else if (_data.indexOf('age_')) {
        age = parseInt(_data.split('_')[1]);
    } 
    else if (_data.indexOf('work_')) {
        work = _data.split('_')[1];
    }
}
```